# Elegant way to iterate over heads of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration, generator

Imagine I have a list of `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

I am looking for a Pythonic idiom for doing roughly this:

```
for first_elements in head(mylist):
   # would first yield ["a"], then ["a", "b], then ["a", "b", "c"]
   # until the whole list gets generated as a result, after which the generator
   # terminates.
```

My feeling is telling me that this should exist pretty much built in, but it's eluding me. How
would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do this:

```
def head(A) :
    for i in xrange(1,len(A)+1) :
        yield A[:i]
```

Example:

```
for x in head(["a", "b", "c", "d"]) :
    print x

['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I guess that this is slower (asymptotically) than Martijn Pieters's solution, as a full new list is recreated each time, but this would be faster than his solution, with NumPy arrays.

Comment: @EOL Right, but it has the (possible) advantage that you can freely manipulate the generated 'heads'.

Comment: I am ticking this one, since I like it for the following reasons: 1) my dataset I am applying it to is small b) I don't like temp variables - even though accumulating the "head" in an extra list is a good speculative move not to generate extra lists.

Comment: or use `xrange(len(A))` then `yield A[:i + 1]`.

Comment: ... or `for i, _ in enumerate(A): yield A[:i+1]`

Comment: @tobias_k: `for i, _ in enumerate(A, 1): yield A[:i]`

Answer (score 7):

You mean this?

```
def head(it):
    val = []
    for elem in it:
        val.append(elem)
        yield val
```

This takes any iterable, not just lists.

Demo:

```
>>> for first_elements in head('abcd'):
...     print first_elements
... 
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: How will this behave when you yield one element, modify it, and then yield the next? (Not saying that this has to be a problem; surely more efficient than creating a new list each time.)

Comment: @tobias_k: the list is shared, so it'll affect all future yields. We can make it a tuple if you like, just use `yield tuple(val)`. :-)

Comment: Do you really need `iter`? Couldn't you just use a simple `for` loop (instead of `while`)?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean and it solves the problem. However I'm not a fan of temp variables when I don't actually need them, so I like the solution with returning a slice better (even though it's less readable).

Comment: @Julik: take into account that that version requires a sequence, mine also accepts any iterable (including generators).

Comment: @Julik: Sorry, can't help you there! :-)